# Iframe in Angular

Tags: angular, iframe

I simply tried to include an iframe in my angular app.
But the Iframe seems to be really small just like in this example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iframe-src?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

How can i implement the iframe over the whole page?

Code:

```
<iframe src="here is the link" style="border:0px #ffffff none;" 
    name="name" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
    marginheight="0px" margin- width="0px" height="100%" width="100%" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `iframe` is set to use 100% height but html and body element have `undefined` height. Find parent `HTML` and `BODY` tag and set height to 100%. This will fix your issue.